# Can I get action alias set by HttpGet to include a css file with the same name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to include `.css` files based on the controller and action like this in my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@{
    var actionCssName = 
        $"{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]}." +
        $"{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]}.css";
}
<link href="/css/@actionCssName" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to reference a `.css` file with such names as: `css/Controller.Action.css`

At the same time, the action in my controller does not use the *default* name but is decorated with `HttpGet`:

```
[HttpGet("report")]
public IActionResult GetReport()
{
    return View("Report", new ReportBody { ... });
}
```

Unfortunatelly `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]` returns the name `GetReport` instead of `report` which does not match the `.css` file because the final name is `css/TestController.GetReport.css`. I'd rather  not rename it if it is possible to get the *alias* for the action.

Or am I doing this completely wrong and there is another way that actually works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either have to change your method name from `GetReport` to `Report`

```
[HttpGet("report")]
public IActionResult Report()
{
    return View("Report", new ReportBody { ... });
}
```

Or you can use `ActionName` Attribute

```
[HttpGet("report")]
[ActionName("Report")]
public IActionResult GetReport()
{
    return View("Report", new ReportBody { ... });
}
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't know the `ActionNameAttribute`.

Comment: I was reading the docs and there is actually a much _better_ way then building the file name manually. It can be generated with the `IUrlHelper` and appropriate routes.